# What is difference between Android memory management and Linux memory management?

Tags: android, linux, memory-management

What is difference between Android memory management and Linux memory management?
I read

```
Android does not use swap
```

in https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html#ViewingAllocations

How to understand?

Comment: Android runs on a Linux kernel. And many Linux systems (e.g. the one embedded in a consumer router or box) don't use swap neither.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Does the swap is optional?

Comment: Of course swap is optional.... Your consumer router (running [WRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT)...) don't have swap space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's saying Android does not dump pages of ram to persistent storage.

If you run out of memory, as a kernel you have a few options, free memory by killing processes, or dump the process image (or pieces of it) to persistent storage.  The pieces are called pages and the area of persistent storage you use to dump pages is called, on Linux, swap space, or on Windows, your pagefile.

Android takes an interesting approach.  Instead of serializing your entire process image, you essentially serialize only the critical parts of your application.  In general, the parts of your application the system serializes is the state information and navigation information.  If the system agrees to parcel up your state information, then it can just recreate your Views and reset their state to how they were when your process was killed to reclaim memory.  It's a pretty good compromise because it forces good application design and prevents thrashing.

Comment: Does this is in order to save storage memory?

Comment: No, doing so would increase the memory available.  But it comes at a performance cost.  And for mobile devices in the past 5 years, storage has been too slow for that to really be an option.  It leads to a subpar user experience if you're always thrashing.  Remember windows 15 years ago?